# SFDX: Authorize an Org hangs after login attempt

Tags: salesforcedx, oauth, authorization

All,

I am on a Windows 10 laptop with the latest patches and updates from Microsoft Version 10.0.18363.  When I attempt to Authorize an Org it opens Google Chrome Version 88.0.4324.190 (Official Build) (64-bit).  I login using the login I've been using successfully since yesterday, I get the prompt to Allow Access, and it just hangs.  I am currently running VS Code Version: 1.53.2.  I have the Salesforce Extension Pack v51.2.0, and the same for the Salesforce CLI Integration.

I'm using sfdcLoginUrl = https://test.salesforce.com

When I execute the Authorize an Org it sends me to the following URL provided I have Revoked the previous attempt:
https://<my_org_name>/setup/secur/RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp?source="very long string"

1. I am unable to find port 1717 running using suggestions previously mentioned.
2. I have uninstalled VS Code twice and deleted everything the second time before re-installing.
3. I have switched the Default browser to Edge each time and this doesn't work.  I even tried IE once!!
4. I look for node.js running and if I kill that process the web browser immediately throws me into the unable to open local port 1717.
5. I've tried sfdx auth:web:login instead of sfdx force:auth:web:login and this does not work.
6. After the failed attempts I Revoke the Salesforce CLI found under my login ID.
7. In my troubleshooting I've seen OAuth Error
8. I have set the Google Chrome to run in Windows 8 compatibility mode as well.  This doesn't help either.
9. I added the C:\Windows\System32 to the PATH environment variable as well.
10. I also tried logging in with our Salesforce Admin credentials and that didn't work either.

What am I missing here.  Can someone please advise?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Most of us have this issue with Authorization command. Something may be broken in cli.

One workaround is with [this command](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_auth_device.htm):

```
// authorize production org
sfdx auth:device:login

// authorize sandbox 
sfdx auth:device:login -r https://test.salesforce.com

// authorize devhub
sfdx auth:device:login -d -a <devhub alias>
```

---

Here is the link to [related issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/371) in GitHub. Another workaround mentioned is to set default browser to Edge or Firefox instead of Google Chrome.

Comment: Raul, thank you for the reply.  That works but forces me to go to production.  Is there a way to specify the sandbox?

Comment: Added the second command to specify instance url from documentation.

Comment: Raul, I had tried that and I get the following error message: ERROR running auth:device:login:  Value is not an string.  The error message came from the second command.

Comment: I am not sure, its working fine for me.

Comment: Please [update sfdx](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/270606/can-not-update-sfdx/270615#270615) cli and try again

Comment: Raul, I tried that and I still have the same result.  Even after closing VS Code and starting again.

Comment: to be clear the update installed version: 7.89.2-d1d2614d02

Comment: I just went back and tried all of the things I tried above after the Update.  Switched browsers, checked for port 1717 running and it still doesn't work.  Does anyone know how to get support from Salesforce for the CLI?  Thank you.

Comment: I linked the github issue, either you can comment on that if you have same problem or open a new issue in that repo.

Comment: All,

Thanks to ImJohnMDaniel I've got it fixed.  
1. Go to the following URL:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode
2. Download an older version, I downloaded 50.16.0
3. Uninstall any of the Salesforce extensions in VS Code
4. Restart the VS Code and click on the Extensions, and the three dots at the top
5. Then click on the Install from SVIX...
6. And, point it to the file you just downloaded.
7. I restarted VS Code to be on the safe side but I'm back up and running.
Thank you everyone.

Comment: @SAM worth adding that as a answer here.

Comment: I have the same issue with edge and firefox, updated cli to 7.90.2

Comment: sfdx auth:device:login works but you have to set it as the default org in a separate step if your setting up a new environment force:config:set defaultusername=[username]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error since a few days. Simply doing a "sfdx update" in the command line solved the problem for me...

Currently I'm on sfdx-cli version 7.88.4 (sfdx --version)

Comment: Chris, thanks for the reply.  I did perform the update and I now have the latest version, but I'm still getting the same issue.  Tried shutting down VS Code and restarting but that didn't work either!!

Comment: Please this thread for the latest informationj:https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/890#issuecomment-789618346

Answer (score 1):

I am also exactly facing the same issue from one week, today I have updated CLI, updated from 7.89.2 to 7.90.2

after this update problem got resolved